# How can I know if an indexedDB request loop has ended or not?

Tags: javascript, request, indexeddb

I am using indexedDB to store some offline data. In my code there is a loop inserting values to a store object:

```
function Insert(){
   for(var i in list)
       InsertList(list[i]);
   alert("successful");
}

function InsertList(str){
            var trans = LocalDB.indexedDB.db.transaction(StoreList, IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
            var store = trans.objectStore(StoreList);
            var data = {
                "item": str};
            var request = store.put(data);
            request.onsuccess = function (e) { };
            request.onerror = function (e) { alert("Error inserting"); };
}
```

The alert message will show before the loop executes, and if the page is refreshed or closed immediately after I close the alert message, some values are not inserted into the list because the loop was interrupted. So how can I know that the loop has ended and then give a successful message? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indexeddb API is async. This means you can only get feedback if something ended using a callback method in the success.

In your case I would work differently and insert everything in one transaction. When the transaction is completed, you get a callback. If that is called you can be sure everything is saved and the inserts are completed.

```
function Insert(){
    var trans = LocalDB.indexedDB.db.transaction(StoreList, IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
    var store = trans.objectStore(StoreList);
    for(var i in list)
    {
        var data = { "item": list[i]};
        var request = store.put(data);
        request.onsuccess = function (e) { };
        request.onerror = function (e) { alert("Error inserting"); };
    }

    trans.oncomplete = function ()
    {
        alert("successful");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works! And we can open multiple stores in one transaction, processing loops for each store, and finally use the 'oncomplete' event to inform users.